# Should 4xx status codes be considered errors in a Frontend/SSR application?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, monitoring, sentry, datadog

We're implementing logging & monitoring for a Vue/Node application which is using a REST Api.

Oftentimes the API returns 4xx reponses (401s, 404s) which are currently caught by Axios and returned as "Errors".

These end up in our logging solutions (Datadog, Sentry) but dont bring much actionable points.

Should in general  status codes like these be considered Errors? Are there any best practices for SPA logging and monitoring? (couldn't find any resources)

Answer (score 2):

See [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

The categories are generally:

- Informational responses (100–199)
- Successful responses (200–299)
- Redirects (300–399)
- Client errors (400–499)
- Server errors (500–599)

So 4XX errors are errors, but they indicate the client is likely at fault. E.g. The user went to a page or user agent made a request to a page that does not exist. The server responds with 404 because "Everything on my end is fine, but that page isn't real."

Is it an error? Sure. Could you potentially identify issues (e.g. typos in links, missing pages, misspellings, malformed API requests, etc..) by routing these to your logs? Sure.

Are you obligated to take action on it? Not if you don't want to.

You're probably best to determine why you feel they are not actionable. Most likely are actionable.

- Is there lots of traffic to a page that doesn't exist? Maybe a redirect should be put in place.
- Is there some activity being rate limited? Perhaps the frequency of those requests needs adjusted or content should be cached, etc..

Comment: We have many requests by scrapers and bots that the only action we can take is blacklist their IPs.. I guess that's something?

Comment: Yeah, retaining those logs could help identifying those users via patterns, IP, user agent, or geo-location. You can also discard them, but you'll discard valid user errors along with them if you do.